# Can an anonymous class extend HashMap with parameters?

Tags: java, collections, dictionary, parameters, extends

I would like create anonymous class that extends `Map`. I try:

```
Collection<? extends Map<String, String> a = new HashMap<String, String>(){};
```

Receive error:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from new HashMap<String,String>(){} to Collection<? extends Map<String,String>>
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Why are you assigning a `HashMap` to a `Collection`? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I would like create anonimous class that extends Map

Comment: Why exactly do you want to do that?

Comment: For unit test. I have object that extends map.

Comment: Map is an interface - you cannot extend it with a class. You can implement it if that is what you need or you can extend a concrete Map class such as HashMap.

Comment: understood. I thought that interface is a type and class is a type, it possible that class extends some class also extends its type...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Collection<? extends Map<String, String> a ;
```

It is the reference of collection of maps (or class that implements map). you can initialize it like -

```
Collection<? extends Map<String, String>> a = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>(){};
```

And this collection object will store list of `HashMap`.

Answer (score 2):

For creating an anonymous implementation of `Map` use this:

```
 Map<String, String> a = new Map<String, String>() { ... }
```

or (if you want to extend HashMap)

```
 Map<String, String> a = new HashMap<String, String>() { ... }
```

There's no need for `Collection...` and this wouldn't work anyways, since a map is no collection with the meaning of that interface (and thus it doesn't implement `Collection`).

Comment: for this I need implement all methods in interface map. It is not trivial

Comment: @user710818 that's why I also included the second option (to extend `HashMap`). You need a implementation anyways so either you provide your own or extend an existing.

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap` does not implement `Collection`.

I think what you are trying to do is simply:

```
Map<String, String> a = new HashMap<String, String>();
```